# IBM worklight Native to Hybrid Migration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

If there is an already existing Android app and now it has to be turned into hybrid app supporting both Android and iOS, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Native Android apps are written in Java.
Hybrid apps are written in HTML, JS and CSS.

You will need to recreate your logic and UI from scratch.